# Scrollbars show when jquery.show() is called

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a flydown menu that has a scrollable div in it that about 400 pixels in height and then scrollbars will show in that drop down. When i hover over it i call the show method like so:

```
$("#flydown").show();
```

The menu shows fine, however when i show the drop down menu the whole page have scrollbars that appear. And if i scroll down its just whitespace.

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you add an example to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have HTML tag mis-match. Check that every `<div>` has a corresponding `</div>` and that there are no extra `<div>` or `</div>` floating around. This is a common cause of massive areas of whitespace.